# Xubuntu 20.04 no internet connection and no sound

Tags: networking, sound, xubuntu

Yesterday all worked fine, but today internet stopped working. And sound disappeared too.

Maybe it's because of last day's update? WI-FI and live USB work normal, so it's not hardware issues.

It says "no network devices available", can't see my router.

How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I didn't have linux-headers and linux-image-extra stuff from kernel. They didn't downloaded somehow.

Luckily I've been able to use 'recovery mode', boot from old old kernel, and download missing elements with Synaptic.